Power calculations based on a subgroup
I'm designing an RCT looking at the effect of a dietary supplement on blood pressure. The nature of the supplement is that it is appealing to both normotensive and hypertensive individuals, therefore, although the likelihood is that the supplement will be more effective at lowering BP in hypertensive individuals, I don't want to exclude normotensive individuals from recruitment. However, including individuals with a wide range of blood pressure measurements makes the likely standard deviation very high and therefore the participants required to detect statistically significant changes very high.
Is it statistically acceptable to do power calculations based on hypertensive individuals and use these individuals in the primary outcome analysis, but still accept normotensive individuals into the trial and include them in a larger post-hoc analysis, or is this considered bad practice?
Thanks for your help

Why not include degree of hypertension as a covariate in the analyses?

For a power analysis you generally want the power to match your analysis. As @whuber wrote, what will your statistical analysis look like? Will it have a covariate, for example. When you know that you can answer the power question.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The first question has to do with what you want the study to accomplish. If all you care about is the effect of the supplement on blood pressure (BP) in hypertensive individuals, the study would certainly be less expensive if it were to be limited to those with high BP. If resources are available then you could include others in the trial; perhaps you were thinking of using them separately as a pilot study to gauge whether a larger study of normotensive individuals might be warranted.
If you have the resources to do a study on all individuals, however, then consider now how you might analyze the study results (as recommended in comments). An informative design and analysis would be to record the pre-study BP for all, do the random treatment assignments, and then model post-study BP as a function of the pre-study BP, the treatment, and an interaction between pre-study BP and treatment. That includes the "degree of hypertension" (pre-study BP) as a predictor, as recommended by @whuber in a comment. The model would be something like the following in the syntax used by R:
postBP ~ treatment + preBP + treatment:preBP

Proper randomization would balance out other potential covariates, so that they might be omitted from the analysis. The interaction term from that type of model, treatment:preBP, would directly demonstrate whether and how much "the supplement will be more effective at lowering BP in hypertensive individuals." That type of model might even be called for if you restrict to hypertensive individuals, as there's no reason to assume that there's some cutoff above which there's a fixed effect of the supplement.
As the relationship between postBP and preBP might not be linear (as implicitly assumed in the above formula), you should consider fitting preBP flexibly, e.g. with a regression spline. If there will be multiple BP observations during the study, model all observations as functions of the above predictors and time. See Chapter 7 of Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies for guidance on how to analyze such a study.
You seem to be worried about the high standard deviation among BP measurements if you include all individuals. If you want to know how the association of treatment with postBP varies as a function of preBP, however, that's a plus. You typically want a broad distribution of any predictor that you care about. You might have been worried about a high standard deviation of the postBP-preBP differences, but modeling the interaction and using actual BP values instead of differences overcomes that problem.
To estimate power for any model you have to make assumptions about the magnitudes of the associations of predictors with outcome that you want to have a chance to detect. You will need to make more assumptions for the model with the interaction, but you can readily simulate a wide range of scenarios to help organize your thoughts and to use for estimating the sample size needed to attain the necessary power under any set of assumptions.
